# Documenting event listeners with JSDoc

Tags: javascript, events, constructor, document, jsdoc

I have this class constructor:

```
/**
 * @class Game renderer.
 * @exports Renderer
 * @constructor
 * @param {number=} width canvas width. Defaults to 1024.
 * @param {number=} height canvas height. Defaults to 720.
 */
var Renderer = function(width, height) {
    'use strict';

    // more code ...

    document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
};
```

How should I document the last line? and if I have event listener? For example:

```
canvas.onmousemove = function(event) {
  // do something
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [@listens](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-listens.html) tag of JSDOC3, :)